# Can't get 2 words with space in post request in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Problem space in post request in Joomla.

txtstring="ABC DBC" but retrieve post txtstring it can get only ABC

HTML CODE:

```
<input type='text' name='txtstring' id='txtstring'>
```

PHPcode (in module):

```
echo $_POST['txtstring'];
```

Result:

ABC

**We need = ABC DBC**

How to fix space between 2 words in Joomla  ?

Comment: Two possible explanations - some client-side script that strips the field value, or client side fiddling with $_POST array...

Comment: remember to always use `htmlentities()` function when outputting user submitted data..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, how is this relevant?

Comment: Of course I haven't! But could you explain how htmlentities would help to solve OPs problem?

Comment: @JamSva: htmlentities($value)

Comment: @Briedis: It wouldn't. It was just a warning for future uses

Comment: You'll need to post a lot ore code to get this figured out. There's nothing wrong with the 2 lines you posted.

Comment: did you try to send "ABC%20ABC" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [JRequest::getString()](http://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines#String) in your module.